# Nextjs CORS issue for relative fonts import

Tags: webpack, sass, next.js

When I compile my nextjs app to production and deploy it, I get CORS error when trying to load my fonts.

I do not have this problem when developing locally. I thought nextjs would automatically process my fonts through webpack and take care of all this.

Within my SCSS I load a relative font in both `.eot` and `.woff2` format. In development `(localhost:3000)` this works just fine.

---

**How I import my scss to the next js app**
**_app.js**

```
import "assets/scss/global.scss";
```

---

**My SCSS loading the font (assets/scss/global.scss)**

```
@font-face
{
    font-family: 'boxicons';
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;

    src: url('../../../../fonts/boxicons.eot');
    src: url('../../../../fonts/boxicons.eot') format('embedded-opentype'),
    url('../../../../fonts/boxicons.woff2') format('woff2'),
    url('../../../../fonts/boxicons.woff') format('woff'),
    url('../../../../fonts/boxicons.ttf') format('truetype'),
    url('../../../../fonts/boxicons.svg?#boxicons') format('svg');
}
```

---

**Console Error In production**

```
Access to font at 'webpack:///mini-css-extract-plugin/_next/static/media/boxicons.6761648c.woff2' from origin 'https://www.myapp.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, brave, chrome-untrusted, https.
```

Comment: Do you have any custom webpack configuration in `next.config.js`? Also, if you move the fonts folder to the `public` folder and reference them as `url('/fonts/boxicons.eot')` does the issue still persist?

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same problem and fixed it this way. Instead of using css to set the font family , i used the method prefered by next js. For reference visit https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/font-optimization#local-fonts

1. Install @next/font in your project `npm i @next/font`
2. `import localFont from '@next/font/local`
3. create a variable for your local font `const myFont = localFont({ src: './my-font.woff2' })`
4. Add a classname to the element you want to apply the font family as   `<div className={myFont.className}>`

here is what your component should look like:

```
import localFont from '@next/font/local'
const myFont = localFont({ src: './my-font.woff2' })

// Font files can be colocated inside of `pages`  
export default function Mycomponent() {
    return (
           <div className={myFont.className}>
              Hello world
            </div>
      )
    }
```